# Android Debugging of an app from the market

Tags: android, debugging

I have an app on my phone, which I downloaded on the market but did not develop. Long story short, it always crashes when I try to open it up. I'd like to know what exceptions are being thrown.

Before I start digging, is this even possible? Any suggestions on where to start digging?

I am a programer but have never done Android development.

Comment: I think that the errors appear on the developer homepage, so perhaps inform the developer to check the errors.. I'm not aware of any other debugging process for an app that you have not developed yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely you cannot debug the application.  Developers usually turn off debugging support when they submit an application to the market for security and intellectual property reasons, so your best bet is to report the crashes to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have done this on apps of my own that have been published;

When it pops up the "Force Close/Report" dialog, click report, then "Preview", and 6th from the bottom it has "Exception class name", which method, which line, and the very useful stack trace, which will let you know everything you'd like.